# Django - adding another check to my login

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a single page application that uses Django's session authentication on the backend. Django is using [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for everything authentication-related.

I would like to add an additional step to my login where the user inputs a code and Django must verify that code too, other than password and username. How can i do that?

Note that i'm using Django as an API, so i don't need to edit the form and add another field, i only need to add another check to the authentication backend, so something very easy: if the code is right, than proceed to check username and password too, else return an error.

The problem is that i don't know where to add this check. I think i need to work on the authentication backend, but i'm stuck here.

Here is an example of the login data that django receives:

```
{'login': 'test', 'password': 'testPass12', 'testToken': '123abc'}
```

So basically, other than checking login and password like it already does now, it should check if `testToken` is equal to a specific value.

Here is the [allauth authentication backend](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/auth_backends.py):

```
class AuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, **credentials):
        ret = None
        if app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL:
            ret = self._authenticate_by_email(**credentials)
        elif app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == AuthenticationMethod.USERNAME_EMAIL:
            ret = self._authenticate_by_email(**credentials)
            if not ret:
                ret = self._authenticate_by_username(**credentials)
        else:
            ret = self._authenticate_by_username(**credentials)
        return ret

    def _authenticate_by_username(self, **credentials):
        username_field = app_settings.USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD
        username = credentials.get("username")
        password = credentials.get("password")

        User = get_user_model()

        if not username_field or username is None or password is None:
            return None
        try:
            # Username query is case insensitive
            user = filter_users_by_username(username).get()
            if self._check_password(user, password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def _authenticate_by_email(self, **credentials):
        # Even though allauth will pass along `email`, other apps may
        # not respect this setting. For example, when using
        # django-tastypie basic authentication, the login is always
        # passed as `username`.  So let's play nice with other apps
        # and use username as fallback
        email = credentials.get("email", credentials.get("username"))
        if email:
            for user in filter_users_by_email(email):
                if self._check_password(user, credentials["password"]):
                    return user
        return None

    def _check_password(self, user, password):
        ret = user.check_password(password)
        if ret:
            ret = self.user_can_authenticate(user)
            if not ret:
                self._stash_user(user)
        return ret

    @classmethod
    def _stash_user(cls, user):
        """Now, be aware, the following is quite ugly, let me explain:
        Even if the user credentials match, the authentication can fail because
        Django's default ModelBackend calls user_can_authenticate(), which
        checks `is_active`. Now, earlier versions of allauth did not do this
        and simply returned the user as authenticated, even in case of
        `is_active=False`. For allauth scope, this does not pose a problem, as
        these users are properly redirected to an account inactive page.
        This does pose a problem when the allauth backend is used in a
        different context where allauth is not responsible for the login. Then,
        by not checking on `user_can_authenticate()` users will allow to become
        authenticated whereas according to Django logic this should not be
        allowed.
        In order to preserve the allauth behavior while respecting Django's
        logic, we stash a user for which the password check succeeded but
        `user_can_authenticate()` failed. In the allauth authentication logic,
        we can then unstash this user and proceed pointing the user to the
        account inactive page.
        """
        global _stash
        ret = getattr(_stash, "user", None)
        _stash.user = user
        return ret

    @classmethod
    def unstash_authenticated_user(cls):
        return cls._stash_user(None)
```

And here is the [allauth login view](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py):

```
class LoginView(
    RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView
):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "account/login." + app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION
    success_url = None
    redirect_field_name = "next"

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(LoginView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["request"] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get_form_class(self):
        return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, "login", self.form_class)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        try:
            return form.login(self.request, redirect_url=success_url)
        except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
            return e.response

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
        ret = (
            get_next_redirect_url(self.request, self.redirect_field_name)
            or self.success_url
        )
        return ret

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signup_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(
            self.request, reverse("account_signup"), self.redirect_field_name
        )
        redirect_field_value = get_request_param(self.request, self.redirect_field_name)
        site = get_current_site(self.request)

        ret.update(
            {
                "signup_url": signup_url,
                "site": site,
                "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value,
            }
        )
        return ret
```

Comment: You could subclass allauth's `LoginForm` with your own `CustomLoginForm`, then add a `ValidationError` to the `clean` method to check the value. The `LoginView` would then use `form_class = CustomLoginForm`. There might be an easier way though. Just one idea.

Comment: This is a good way to go. To be honest i'm finding some different ways that could work, the only problem i'm having with all of them is how to return the error if the token is not right, just like it does when the username or the password are wrong

Comment: I think just raising a ValidationError on the form would do it. See the [ValidationError in the clean method](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/353386216b79f16709e97bb487c0bbbba2bc0c71/allauth/account/forms.py#L172).

Comment: True. If there is a way to do this without touching the source code from the library i might follow this approach, i think there should be a way to override allauth forms and views